# Why do I keep losing 2 rep, even though I don't get downvoted?

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-history

Nowadays, I notice that I lose 2 rep when I check SO in the morning. I look through my feed, and it doesn't say I got downvoted. It doesn't show up in my feed, but I remember I had 1,116 yesterday, and now I have 1,114.

I have triple checked my reputation tab, and it doesn't say **anything** about losing 2 rep.

I have also looked at similar question, but none of them apply.

Some might say it isn't a big deal, and I agree, but I was just wondering. It's really adding up.

Comment: You'll want to avoid suggesting edits to questions that need to be closed. If you look at [the timeline for this question you edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62144140/timeline) your edit was approved *after* the question was closed, which pushed it into the re-open queue where it of course was voted to Remain Closed. At 1-, there's a very good chance this question will end up deleted.

Comment: @BSMP Yes, I should stop doing edits for posts that are going to be closed. Usually I do it when I find a post of that type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Posts where you had suggested an edit that was accepted have been deleted.

If you look at your [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12708583/themaker?tab=reputation) you should see an entry that reads:

```
-2    13 hours ago    removed    [Question Title]
```

I, as a moderator, can certainly see that line though if I open the page in an incognito window I can't. I'm hoping that you, as the "owner" of that page, will also be able to see it. You will have to enable the "show removed posts" option at the bottom of the page.

The reputation is removed as, in general, you don't earn reputation from deleted posts. There is an exception for posts older than 60 days that have a score of +3 or more, but that doesn't apply to suggested edits.

Comment: Why should I get punished because someone else did a bad post?

Comment: @TheMaker Well we could counter with: Why should you get rewarded for doing something that hasn't helped anyone?

Comment: @TheMaker The only way to keep the 2 reputation points on a deleted post, is if the post is deleted **before** the edit is approved. I suspect it's a bug, though.

Comment: @Scratte IIRC that 2 reputation is removed once the next full reputation recalculation happens.

Comment: @gparyani That would make sense, but in my case it didn't. I still have them.

Comment: @RobertLongson It might have helped a few people before the post got deleted.